# C/C++ Include two copies of the same library (different code, same method names/variable names)

Tags: c++, c, include, shared-libraries

I have two C solvers generated by CVXGEN, and I need to use them both in my code. I need to include solver.h from both of the solvers, which each contains a lot of structs and functions. It would be really hard to rename them all in all of the code (about 10k lines per solver). Is there a way to include them and use them in my code at the same time?

Comment: yes create namespace

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace

Comment: The solutions for this problem differ greatly between C and C++. Which is the target language?

Comment: The library (solver) that I am including is itself written in C, and my code is in C++.

Comment: That's that I figured. Start with @HariomSingh 's suggestion. This should be as simple as wrapping just about everything in the headers and C files for the first solver in `namespace solver1 { code goes here }` and hoping that a C++ compiler will happily compile the solvers (usually does). If it works, I'd also wrap the second solver for consistency.

Comment: I am getting "unknown type name 'namespace'" when I try to compile, with or without using inline `extern"C"` while including the solvers.
These are my cmake flags:
inline `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -Os -fno-diagnostics-color -Wall")`